# ¿Es posible pasar variables get de una pagina a un iframe y que el iframe los pase a un archivo que carga con un include?

Tags: php, html, get, iframe

Estoy trabajando en un sitio en el cual la parte que me toca desarrollar se muestra en un **iframe** de la página principal, la página principal le envía datos al **iframe** por **GET**, la parte que desarrollo (la que va en el iframe) contiene un **div** que carga contenido dinámico, osea los **href** de unas etiquetas hacen que cambie el contenido del div, el código **php** para hacer ese cambio después de que en el href pongo `href="?modulo=grid"` por ejemplo, es el siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['modulo'])) {
    switch ($_GET['modulo']) {
        case "catalogo":
            include "modulos/catalogo.php";
            break;
        case "listado":
            include "modulos/listado.php";
            break;
        case "grid":
            include "modulos/grid.php";
            break;
        case "ayuda":
            include "modulos/ayuda.php";
            break;
        default:
            echo "VISTA NO ENCONTRADA";
    }
} else {
    include "modulos/catalogo.php";
}
?>
```

En modo local sin estar incrustado en el iframe funciona, quisiera saber si algo falta, ya intente pasar las mismas variables que pasa la página al iframe por medio del href de esta manera:

```
href="?u=<?php $_GET['u']?>&e=<?php $_GET['e']?>&i=<?php $_GET['i']?>&modulo=catalogo"
```

Pero no tuve resultado. Agradecería su ayuda, Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con la ruta completa en el iframe, desde `http://`.

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, así como tienes tu primer cuadro de código, lo que vas a hacer es declararlo en una variable, el nombre de dicha variable es el que vas a utilizar dentro del archivo el cual vas a hacer un `include()`.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tienes un archivo que se llama `procesa.php` el cual tiene el contenido siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['modulo'])) {
    switch ($_GET['modulo']) {
        case "catalogo":
            include "modulos/catalogo.php";
            break;
        case "listado":
            include "modulos/listado.php";
            break;
        case "grid":
            include "modulos/grid.php";
            break;
        case "ayuda":
            include "modulos/ayuda.php";
            break;
        default:
            echo "VISTA NO ENCONTRADA";
    }
} else {
    include "modulos/catalogo.php";
}
?>
```

Para que puedas llegar a ese archivo necesitas o haber mandado un **form** o con un **enlace** que llevara como parametro el **modulo**.

```
<a href="/procesa.php?modulo=grid">Enviar</a>
```

Pero para poder cargar variables dentro de tu `include()` es necesario que se envíen los demás datos.

```
<a href="/procesa.php?u=<?= $_GET['u']?>&e=<?= $_GET['e']?>&i=<?= $_GET['i']?>&modulo=grid">Enviar</a>
```

Y tu archivo procesa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['modulo'], $_GET['e'], $_GET['u'], $_GET['i'])) {
    $e = $_GET['e'];
    $u = $_GET['u'];
    $i = $_GET['i'];
    switch ($_GET['modulo']) {
        case "catalogo":
            include "modulos/catalogo.php";
            break;
        case "listado":
            include "modulos/listado.php";
            break;
        case "grid":
            include "modulos/grid.php";
            break;
        case "ayuda":
            include "modulos/ayuda.php";
            break;
        default:
            echo "VISTA NO ENCONTRADA";
    }
} else {
    include "modulos/catalogo.php";
}
?>
```

Si tus variables **GET** existen al llegar a `procesa.php` entonces entra al **if**, se declaran las 3 variables a pasar a el `include()` y dichas variables ya pueden ser usadas dentro del **include** que se elija.

Si por ejemplo se mando el de **grid**, quiere decir que dentro de `grid.php` podrás utilizar `$e`, `$u` y `$i`.